# How to get total count from query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my query

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.venue_id, 
        a.user_id, 
        m1.profilenam AS user_profilename,
        m1.photo_thumb AS user_photo_thumb,
        m2.profilenam AS venue_profilename, 
        m2.photo_thumb AS venue_photo_thumb 
FROM announce_arrival AS a 
    INNER JOIN members AS m1 
        ON a.user_id = m1.mem_id
    INNER JOIN members AS m2 
        ON a.venue_id = m2.mem_id
GROUP BY a.venue_id, a.user_id
LIMIT 0,10 
ORDER BY date DESC,
         time DESC
```

How can i use count(*) on this query,i use like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) 
 FROM announce_arrival AS a       
 INNER JOIN members as m1 ON (a.user_id = m1.mem_id)
 INNER JOIN members as m2 ON (a.venue_id= m2.mem_id)
 GROUP BY a.venue_id, a.user_id LIMIT 0,10  ORDER BY date DESC,time DESC;
```

but its showing
COUNT(*)
7
3
1

i want total count .

Comment: I think you'll have to remove the group by

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your query into select count(*), like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
  (SELECT a.id,a.venue_id, a.user_id, m1.profilenam as
    user_profilename,m1.photo_thumb AS user_photo_thumb,m2.profilenam AS
    venue_profilename, m2.photo_thumb AS venue_photo_thumb FROM announce_arrival
    AS a INNER JOIN members as m1 ON (a.user_id = m1.mem_id) INNER JOIN members
    as m2 ON (a.venue_id= m2.mem_id) GROUP BY a.venue_id, a.user_id)
```

Comment: @RockDance, just add an alias to the end of this query `as x`

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your query in another SELECT:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) 
FROM announce_arrival AS a       
INNER JOIN members as m1 ON (a.user_id = m1.mem_id)
INNER JOIN members as m2 ON (a.venue_id= m2.mem_id)
GROUP BY a.venue_id, a.user_id LIMIT 0,10  ORDER BY date DESC,time DESC) AS t
```

or if you want sum of all `DISTINCT COUNT(*)` try:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) AS total FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM announce_arrival AS a       
INNER JOIN members as m1 ON (a.user_id = m1.mem_id)
INNER JOIN members as m2 ON (a.venue_id= m2.mem_id)
GROUP BY a.venue_id, a.user_id LIMIT 0,10  ORDER BY date DESC,time DESC) AS t
```

Answer (score 1):

From [docs about `found_rows()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

> To obtain this row count, include a
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the
>   SELECT statement, and then invoke
>   FOUND_ROWS() afterward:
>
> `mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;`
>
> `mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`
>
> The second SELECT returns a number
>   indicating how many rows the first
>   SELECT would have returned had it been
>   written without the LIMIT clause.

I.e., add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` after `SELECT` in your first query and replace second query with `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`.

Comment: Using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` will cause performance issues. In most cases 2 separate queries (`SELECT fields` and `SELECT count(*)`) will be faster.

Comment: It **may** cause performance issues, though it should be tested in each case, if performance matters that much.

Comment: @Nemoden: Depends very much on the query - I haven't seen significant data for one or the other being *usually* faster. Measure and see for yourself, as always :)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `GROUP BY`, `LIMIT` and `ORDER`. They are useless and don't make sense (especially `LIMIT`) if you need a total count. `DISTINCT` doesn't make sense either.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM announce_arrival AS a       
 INNER JOIN members as m1 ON (a.user_id = m1.mem_id)
 INNER JOIN members as m2 ON (a.venue_id= m2.mem_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      SELECT COUNT(a.user_id) 
      FROM announce_arrival AS a       
      INNER JOIN members as m1 ON (a.user_id = m1.mem_id)
      INNER JOIN members as m2 ON (a.venue_id= m2.mem_id)
      GROUP BY  a.user_id LIMIT 0,10;
```

If you are using count no need to give order by